# Eliminando elementos de archivo .json en PHP

Tags: php, json, api, servidor, rest

Estoy trabajando en PHP con un archivo json llamado **comentarios.json** y necesito eliminar elementos por su index, es decir por su posición en el array ya sea 0, 1, 2 o el que le indique por una petición POST desde la aplicación del cliente. El archivo **comentarios.json** contiene lo siguiente:

```
[{"user":"Carl",
  "comment":"Probando",
  "date":"6/11/2022",
  "star":"0"
 },
 {
   "user":"Juan",
  "comment":"Probando 2",
  "date":"6/11/2022",
  "star":"0"
 },
 {
   "user":"María",
   "comment":"Probando 3",
   "date":"6/11/2022",
   "star":"0"}]
```

Y estoy usando json_decode para pasarlo a array y unset para eliminar un elemento, luego json_encode para pasar a json el anterior array y file_put_contents para pasarlo de nuevo al archivo **comentarios.json**, el elemento deseado se borra pero el formato del json cambia al hacer todo esto y resulta así:

```
{"1":
{"user":"Juan",
"comment":"Probando 2",
"date":"6/11/2022",
"star":"0"
},
"2":
{"user":"Maria",
"comment":"Probando 3",
"date":"6/11/2022",
"star":"0"
}}
```

Estoy usando el siguiente código en PHP:

```
<?php
$jsonName = file_get_contents('comentarios.json');
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonName);
unset($phpArray[0]);
echo $fileJson = json_encode($phpArray);                         
file_put_contents('comentarios.json', $fileJson);
?>
```

¿De qué forma puedo eliminar un elemento del mismo y llenar de nuevo el archivo **comentarios.json** manteniendo el mismo formato de cadena del json original?

Comment: Ya volví a añadir todo, ayer usé un json de ejemplo y hoy el real que voy a procesar para que no haya incompatibilidades.

Comment: vale, ahora si que lo he podido reproducir... me lo miro y te digo algo :-)

Comment: Gracias amigo, se nota que apenas hace dos días toqué php por primera vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misterio resuelto. El problema es que al hacer el [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) se borra el registro **pero** se mantienen los números de indice del array conseguido previamente con *json_decode*.

Luego, al hacer de nuevo un *json_encode()*, no interpreta esos índices como tales, pues no son correlativos empezando por 0, y los toma como claves de objeto.

La solución pasa por reindexar el array después de eliminar el registro que deseas con [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) de este modo:

```php
<?php
$jsonName = file_get_contents('comentarios.json');
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonName);
unset($phpArray[0]);
$phpArray = array_values($phpArray);
echo $fileJson = json_encode($phpArray);                         
file_put_contents('comentarios.json', $fileJson);
?>
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección! Ya formatea cómo debe el archivo. Gracias!!

Comment: De nada, un placer contestar buenas preguntas :-) ... No ha sido trivial para mi tampoco (y pensaba que sí lo era) y me ha costado un buen rato hasta que lo he comprendido, je. Saludos!